# .Net Core 5 + Angular 12 Publishing on IIS

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core, .net-5, angular12

While publishing .Net Core 5 + Angular solution to IIS with following setup. I run into this issue.

Application works perfectly fine in development mode.

> What should be starting point of troubleshooting? Is it angular
> publish failing or .Net core ?

**More Details:**

[image]

Following is the publish profile settings I used.

[image]

Comment: If the response starts with `<` it means it's an HTML page, most likely containing the error. If breaks because it was expecting a js file but it's an HTML file. GIve it a look.

Comment: @Abhijeet can you show Startup?